# How to activate RunIfOutofBounds correctly?

Tags: python, back-testing

I'm new here and this is my first question. Therefore, please forgive me if not everything is clearly formulated. Feedback on that is welcome as well.

I try to execute a backtesting using the bt.algos.
As an example I take two ETF with a predefinded allocation (80 to 20)

```
data_bt = bt.get("spy,agg", start="2010-01-01")
weights=data_bt.copy()
weights["spy"]=0.2
weights["agg"]=0.8
tolerance=0.05
```

My algo looks like:

```
s = bt.Strategy("s1",[bt.algos.SelectAll(),
                  bt.algos.RunIfOutOfBounds(tolerance),
                  bt.algos.WeighTarget(weights),
                  bt.algos.Rebalance()])
```

It runs all smooth and I can create a backtest:

```
test = bt.Backtest(s,data_bt)
res=bt.run(test)
res.display()
```

The result (e.g. Total return) is always the same, regardless if the tolerance is 0.5,0.05,0.005 or anything else.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I cannot find the `bt.get` function. Do you know from which package it derives?

Comment: Hi, thank. Yes, I had to install the bt package upfront (pip install bt). See here: https://pmorissette.github.io/bt/

Comment: Ah, wait, is this Python? Your tags contains R, so it is being classified under R.

Comment: Correct, sorry, the R tag was not from me